# Batch single liner for finding files with directory wildcard

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

Consider the following directory structure

```
- Temp\
- Temp\DirA\
- Temp\DirA\Content\
- Temp\DirA\Content\file.txt
- Temp\DirB\
- Temp\DirB\Content\
- Temp\DirB\Content\file.txt
```

Now I want to list all text files inside the content directories in a single line statement. I would expect something like this to work:

```
dir Temp\*\Content\*.txt
```

but it does not (it gives an syntax error). Even forfiles returns an empty result. Is there a convenient way to achive this?

Please note: My real world command will contain multiple wildcards. I don't wanto to combine foreach directory with foreach file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursive `dir /s` and filter the output by `\Content\`:

```
dir /s /b Temp\*.txt Temp\*.log | find "\Content\"
```

And in case you don't need to list the files in `Content\other_folder\` use a regexp:

```
dir /s /b Temp\*.txt Temp\*.log | findstr /r "\\Content\\[^\\]*$"
```

Comment: Well, not what I was hoping but it should get me started. I suppose I will install perl. If I remember correctly this should do the trick:  `perl -e 'foreach (<c:/temp/*/content/*.txt>) { print; print "\n" }'`

Comment: @SchlaWiener, instead of `forfiles` you can do everything in `for /f` parse-loop of the output from the given command and it'll be much faster than `forfiles` in case you have a lot of files. More readable, probably, too.

Comment: Well in unix the find tool I can simply do ` find /etc/*/*.conf -type f` and I thought there might be a direct replacement for windows. Anyway, with perl I can get the same result (or just install unix tools for windows)

Comment: Yep, installing unix tools is the best solution in this case.